# split content of a column pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas Dataframe

[image]

Which can also be generated using this list of dictionaries:

```
list_of_dictionaries = [
    {'Project': 'A', 'Hours': 2, 'people_ids': [16986725, 17612732]},
    {'Project': 'B', 'Hours': 2, 'people_ids': [17254707, 17567393, 17571668, 17613773]},
    {'Project': 'C', 'Hours': 3, 'people_ids': [17097009, 17530240, 17530242, 17543865, 17584457, 17595079]},
    {'Project': 'D', 'Hours': 2, 'people_ids': [17097009, 17584457, 17702185]}]
```

I have implemented kind of what I need, but adding columns vertically:

```
df['people_id1']=[x[0] for x in df['people_ids'].tolist()]
df['people_id2']=[x[1] for x in df['people_ids'].tolist()]
```

And then I get a different column of every single *people_id*, just until the second element, because when I add the extraction 3rd element on a third column, it crashes because , there is no 3rd element to extract from the first row.

[image]

Even though, what I am trying to do is to extract every *people_id* from **people_ids** column, and then each one of those will have their associated value from the **Project** and **Hours** columns, so I get a dataset like this one:

[image]

Any idea on how could I get this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on 'people_ids' column.

```
df = df.explode('people_ids', ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Yes, that's right thanks @SomeDude, it worked just as I needed!!